# Adding an event callback function to a button with a Font Awesome icon inside

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I have a search bar on my header that I made hidden by default with a button next to it to show/hide it depending on certain conditions. I made the button content using Font Awesome where I put a search icon if the search bar is hidden to indicate "show search", and a right chevron icon if the search bar is shown to indicate "hide search."

The way I wrote my js is so that upon clicking the button, if the event target contains certain classes, the search bar will show/hide and the problem is that the event target can be either the `i` element (Font Awesome) or the `button` element. This isn't a problem when clicking to show the search bar, but when clicking to hide it, I can't seem to get the callback function to trigger when the event target is the `button` element. I really hope I'm making sense.

Here's my JSFiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/42uoLsrk/2/

```
function showHideSearch(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    const searchBar = document.querySelector("#search");
    const searchButton = document.querySelector("#search-button");

    if (
        e.target.classList.contains("show-btn") ||
        e.target.classList.contains("fa-search")
    ) {
        searchBar.classList.add("show-search");
        searchButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>`;
    } else if (
        e.target.classList.contains("fa-chevron-right") ||
        e.target.innerHTML == `<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>`
    ) {
        searchBar.classList.remove("show-search");
        searchButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-search"></i>`;
    }
}
```

Line 24 in JS in particular is where I'm struggling:

```
e.target.innerHTML == `<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>`
```

I feel like it really should work, since when the search bar is shown, the `innerHTML` of the `button` element is exactly that, but it's not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an updated version of the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t2jngLfd/). I fixed a few things, first since you're only getting an element by I'd just use `getElementById`. Next the button will always have a fairly chance of being pressed regardless of whether you are closing or opening the input field, so you should create a variable that checks whether the input is open or closed. If it's open and the button is clicked close it and vice versa.

```js
const searchDiv =   document.getElementById("search-div");
let open = false;
// ADD EVENT LISTENERS
searchDiv.addEventListener("click", showHideSearch);

// FUNCTION: SHOW/HIDE SEARCH BAR ON BUTTON CLICK
function showHideSearch(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    const searchBar = document.querySelector("#search");
    const searchButton = document.querySelector("#search-button");
    if (
        (e.target.classList.contains("show-btn") ||
        e.target.classList.contains("fa-search")) && !open
    ) {
        searchBar.classList.add("show-search");
        searchButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>`;            open = true;
    } else if (
       ( e.target.classList.contains("fa-chevron-right") ||
                e.target.id == "search-button") && open
    ) {
        searchBar.classList.remove("show-search");
        searchButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-search"></i>`;
        open = false;
    }
}
```

```css
/* GENERAL */
:root {
    --light-color: #ccc;
    --lighter-color: #f4f4f4;
    --dark-color: #333;
    --darker-color: #222;
    --brand-color: #ff4;
    --danger: #f44;
    --danger-dark: #c00;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: var(--dark-color);
    color: var(--light-color);
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

button,
input {
    outline: none;
}

/* UTILITY */
.highlight {
    color: var(--brand-color);
}

.show-search {
    width: 100% !important;
    border: black 2px solid;
    padding: 0.6rem 1rem;
}

/* HEADER */
header {
    background: var(--darker-color);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1.8rem 6rem;
    width: 100%;
}

#logo {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-weight: 200;
}

#search-div {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    gap: 0.4rem;
}

.show-btn {
    padding: 0.6rem 0.7rem;
    background: var(--light-color);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    transition: ease-in 300ms;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    width: 3rem;
}

.show-btn:hover {
    background: var(--brand-color);
    transition: ease-in 300ms;
}

#search {
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--lighter-color);
    color: var(--darker-color);
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transition: ease-in 300ms;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3ad7573e76.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="logo-div">
            <h1 id="logo">
                <span class="highlight"><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i></span> My<span
                    class="highlight">Contact</span>List
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div id="search-div">
            <button id="search-button" class="show-btn"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
            <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search contacts...">
        </div>
    </header></body>
```

If you require any more clarification please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks a lot, really. This is exactly what I wanted to add but wasn't sure how to do it.